# Unexpected JSON response - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a bar graph that I'm trying to populate with a `JSON` response. I'm using Rails 5 with the built in JBuilder functionality.

Here is my code:

```
def graph_data
  @customers = Customer.all
  @graph_data = {graph_type: "Customer Growth"}
  @months = {}
  x = 5
  while x >= 0
    @months[x.months.ago.strftime("%B")] = current_account.customers.where(:created_at => x.months.ago.beginning_of_month..x.months.ago.end_of_month).count
    x = x - 1
  end
  @graph_data[:months] = @months
  puts @graph_data.to_json

end
```

The line `puts @graph_data.to_json` outputs the following text:

```
{"graph_type":"Customer Growth","months":{"November":0,"December":0,"January":0,"February":0,"March":0,"April":3}}
```

as I would expect.

However, when I output the actual JSON response in my `graph_data.json.jbuilder` file the output is

```
[["graph_type","Customer Growth"],["months",{"November":0,"December":0,"January":0,"February":0,"March":0,"April":3}]]
```

My goal was to get a response that looked more like this:

```
{"graph_type":"Customer Growth","months":["November":0,"December":0,"January":0,"February":0,"March":0,"April":3]}
```

but I don't know how to accomplish this with jBuilder.

Here are the contents of my `graph_data.json.jbuilder` file.

```
json.array! @graph_data
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your jbuilder file, replace

```
json.array! @graph_data
```

to

```
json.graph_type @graph_data[:graph_type]
json.months @graph_data[:months]
```